# Generating Unique ID's for Derived Classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class

I am trying to write a base class, and a set of N derived classes, where each each derived class has its own unique identifier, here is a simple, 'manual' implementation:

```
struct Base {
    static int id_ = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : public Base {
    static int id_ = 1;
};

struct Derived2 : public Base {
    static int id_ = 2;
};
```

The problem is, if I want to continue adding derived classes, I must count the number of already existing derived classes.

Things also get more complicated, because I want to use a bitset to represent the unique ID. If every derived class's unique ID is basically just a different bit (of a common-length bitset) set to 1, it makes it very easy to perform binary AND/OR/XOR/etc operations on groups of derived classes.

The following is a incomplete and incorrect implementation of what I want

```
//Let DCOUNT be the number of derived classes, Ideally I shouldnt have to ever
//know/think about what it evaluates too, it should be automatic.
//But that is second priority, I would be willing to #define this to 
//some 'large' value, and not worry about it.
struct Base {
    static std::bitset<DCOUNT> id_ = generateUniqueID(); // "00000"
};

struct Derived1 {
    static std::bitset<DCOUNT> id_ = generateUniqueID(); // "00001"
};

struct Derived2 {
    static std::bitset<DCOUNT> id_ = generateUniqueID(); // "00010"
};
```

What is the best way to implement this? (or something like it)

Comment: How about making a virtual function that returns a `void*` which is its function ptr?

Comment: Why do you need the `_id`s of classes? This is RTTI (Runtime type information), and it's not good coding practice. Maybe you can solve your problem in a way where you won't need RTTI.

Comment: Do you want these IDs to be the same accross translation units ?

Comment: @alestanis I am trying to build a component Entity system, where container classes (Entities), will each contain a vector of Base Componenet Pointers to Derived Componenet Classes (with unique ID's). This is for a game, so the Id's will let restrict me so that I cant add a Render componenet to an entity, unless that entity has a position and orientation componenet. Is there a better way to implement Entity-Component Systems?

Comment: @Synxis If I am understanding your question, yes; the ID's should be uniform to the derived classes throughout the entire program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something simple like a family of functions (template) that generates and keeps an id for each type, like this:

```
 template<typename T>
 static std::bitset<DCOUNT> getId()
 {
     static std::bitset<DCOUNT> bitset;
     static bool bitsetCreated = false;
     if ( false == bitsetCreated )
     {
        bitset = generateUniqueID();
        bitsetCreated = true;
     }
     return bitset;
 }
```

Afterwards you can get the IDs like this: getId < YourType > ();
They are generated at runtime, so no problem with generateUniqueID();

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information).

You cannot initialize a static member with an external function, you will get compiler errors like

```
'generateUniqueID()' cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

or

```
ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘id_’
```

I think that all you can do is initialize the `id_` values by hand.

You also have an alternative to know the types of your classes: use the `typeid` function, as in

```
if (typeid(myInstance) == typeid(Derived1))
    do_something();
```

Comment: I had feared as much. I will leave this answer unchecked for awhile incase someone else can come up with something.

Comment: Sure :) I just tried doing that with a very simple function just returning an int and got compiler errors for every variant I tried (const, non const...)

Comment: @SamCoulter Added another idea to my answer, maybe it can help